# Is it possible to show KDE panels only for a multimonitor layout?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

I love the flexibility of the Plasma Desktop panels, and I have my laptop + 2 external displays, each with a panel configured differently.

However, when I unplug my laptop, all panels are gathered on my laptop screen and upon re-plugging they remain there.

Is there a way to auto-add and remove panels when new monitors are attached/removed? A scripting solution is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my wanted behavior is actually the desired behavior but it's buggy: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=295784

Hopefully that will get fixed some day...